# Equation about fluxes of the Green's functions of the Laplacian on intersecting domains

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I've got a problem with the divergence theorem, hope someone could help me.
So this is the set up:

Let $\Omega$, $\tilde{\Omega}$ be domains with  $0\in \Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega}$ with boundaries sufficiently smooth that the divergence theorem and the strong maximum principle hold. Let $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ solve
\begin{align} \Delta(u)=-\delta(x) \ \text{in} \ \Omega \ \text{and} \ u=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial\Omega \\
\Delta(\tilde{u})=-\delta(x) \ \text{in} \ \tilde{\Omega} \ \text{and} \ u=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial\tilde{\Omega}
\end{align}
Further we define $v$ to solve
\begin{align}
\Delta(v)=-\delta(x) \ \text{in} \ \Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega} \ \text{and} \ v=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial(\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega})
\end{align}

By the maximum principle we get $0\leq v\leq u$ and $0\leq v\leq \tilde{u}$ on $\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega}$ and in addition $v=u$ on $\partial\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega}$. With defining the flux $F_u:=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ where $n$ is the outward pointing normal the above leads to 
\begin{align}
F_v\leq F_u \ \text{on} \ \partial\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega} \ \text{and} \\
F_v\leq F_{\tilde{u}} \ \text{on} \ \partial\tilde{\Omega}\cap\Omega
\end{align}
Now with the divergence theorem 
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial\Omega_{0}} F_u dS = \int_{\partial\Omega_{0}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} dS = \int_{\Omega_{0}} \Delta u dS
\end{align}
I want to understand how to obtain the equation
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega}} F_u dS + \int_{\partial\Omega\backslash \tilde{\Omega}} F_u dS = \int_{\partial\Omega\cap\tilde{\Omega}} F_v dS+ 
\int_{\partial\tilde{\Omega}\cap\Omega} F_v dS
\end{align}
Does anyone have got an idea about the way to get it?

(Edit: $\overline{\Omega}$ was changed to $\tilde\Omega$)

Thanks

Comment: $\overline\Omega$ is a different domain, right? Might be better to use, for example, $\tilde\Omega$ (`\tilde\Omega`) instead since the former often means the topological closure of $\Omega$.

Comment: Oh sure. Thank you for your comment